# Can I travel from Brussels to Ghent using the JUMP card?

Tags: public-transport, belgium, brussels, ghent

I'm planning to stay in Brussels and visit Ghent as well. On the public transport plan (https://www.belgiantrain.be/en/tickets-and-railcards/jump-ticket), there is an ICE to Ghent included. Does this mean, I can take this ICE from inside Brussels and use my JUMP card to travel to Ghent, as well as travel back the same route to Brussels?

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The JUMP card doesn't work on trains outside of the Brussels region.

On the [jump information page](https://www.belgiantrain.be/en/tickets-and-railcards/jump-ticket) you can [download a map](https://cdn.belgiantrain.be/-/media/files/pdf/productfiches/abonnement/mtb-map.ashx?la=en?v=3ba4f2737ca34e82aec7063a4df269de&hash=E33111949B3780E866697851BD3F0BC2EBA24F04&_ga=2.244692230.2070533606.1572861488-473224733.1567667650) to where you can use your JUMP card.

If you want to take the train (NMBS or SNCB, same company just other names because of different languages in Belgium) from Brussels to Ghent you'll need to buy a ticket.

- If you are -26 years old, a "Go Pass One" is very cheap. (one way ticket)
- If you travel there and back in the weekend (starting friday from 19h), buy a weekend ticket, it's way cheaper.
- If you want to take the train multiple times during the period of a year, the [Rail Pass](https://www.belgiantrain.be/en/tickets-and-railcards/railpass) can be a very good idea. 10 single trips from anywhere to anywhere.

Be aware, Ghent has 2 train stations. You probably want to go to the biggest one: Gent-Sint-Pieters